# What is the difference between those ways to create an object?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have a class name Type.
What is the difference between:

1.

```
Type t=a;
```

2.

```
Type t(a);
```

Where 'a' is some variable.

And what is the difference between:

3.

```
Type t;
```

4.

```
Type t();
```

Thank you.

Edit:
There are some answers which contradict each other. 
Someone has a final answer?

Comment: The 4) `Type t();` is a function declaration. The others are copy constructors/default constructors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Type t=a;
```

This is *copy initialization* (§8.5/15). It requires that `Type` has a non-`explicit` constructor taking an argument of whatever type `a` is, or a type that `a` is implicitly convertible to.

```
Type t(a);
```

This is *direct initialization* (§8.5/16). `t` can be constructed from the argument `a` even if the corresponding constructor is `explicit`.

```
Type t;
```

`t` will be *default initialized* (§8.5/12).

```
Type t();
```

This is a function declaration for a function named `t` that returns `Type` by value (§8.5/11).

Comment: Thank you! I think its the full differences.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** `Type t=a;`  // Copy initialization

**2)** `Type t(a);` // Copy construction (copy constructor or constructor that takes a parameter that has the same type of `a`)

and then :

**1)** `Type t;`    // Default constructor

**2)** `Type t();`  // **NOT a construction** : declaration of a function t that takes nothing and return an object of type Type

Comment: `Type t=a;` is not assignment constructor. There is no assignment here.

Comment: And #2 isn't necessarily a copy constructor. Consider the case where `a` is an `int` and `Type` is a user-defined type.

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
Type t=a;
```

is called copy-initialization.  Constructors marked `explicit` are not considered.

2)

```
Type t(a);
```

is called direct-initialization.  All constructors are considered, both with and without the `explicit` keyword.

3)

```
Type t;
```

is called default-initialization.  The default constructor (one with no arguments or with all arguments defaulted) is called.

4)

```
Type t();
```

declares a function `t` that returns a `Type`.  This is called the Most Vexing Parse.  (`Type t{};` is the same as #3 default-initialization but with a visible empty argument list.)

Comment: For the copy initialization case, it doesn't matter whether the type of `a` is `Type` or derived from `Type` - neither will work if the corresponding constructor, the copy constructor, is `explicit` (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb776cba884dd0cf)

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  The wording in 8.5 confused me, but with a look at 13.3.1.3 I see the real purpose of that wording is to rule out conversion functions in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

`Type t=a;` and `Type t(a);` both are same. Both calls the **copy constructor** if `type` is default type. Otherwise it is object initialization by `1` argument constructor.
`Type t;` calls the **default copy constructor** while `Type t();` is **function declaration**.

Comment: No... #1 and #2 don't both call the copy constructor. In fact, they might not even call a copy constructor at all.